# Subversion E000037: Can't get exclusive lock on file 'db/txn-current-lock': No locks available

Tags: nfs, subversion, lock

When I try to commit a change to a Subversion repository, and I get error messages of the form

```
svn: E000037: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000037: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/path/to/repo/db/txn-current-lock': No locks available
svn: E000037: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn: E000037:    '/path/to/workdir/svn-commit.tmp'
```

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The Subversion code ends up [trying to obtain a lock](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.9.3/subversion/libsvn_subr/io.c) on the `txn-current-lock` file via a call to [`apr_file_lock()`](https://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/2.0/group__apr__file__io.html#ga2d337e66c1fa0cd433164079bf542484).  You should be able to reproduce the error with the following test:

```
#include <apr_general.h>
#include <apr_file_io.h>
#include <apr_pools.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * const *argv, const char * const *env) {
    apr_file_t *f;
    apr_pool_t *pool;
    apr_status_t err;
    char errbuf[200];

    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Need to specify path to file to lock\n");
        return 1;
    }

    apr_app_initialize(&argc, &argv, &env);

    if (0 != (err = apr_pool_create(&pool, NULL))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create APR pool\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (0 != (err = apr_file_open(&f, argv[1], APR_FOPEN_CREATE | APR_FOPEN_WRITE, APR_UREAD | APR_UWRITE, pool))) {
        apr_strerror(err, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Open failed: %s\n", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    if (0 != (err = apr_file_lock(f, APR_FLOCK_EXCLUSIVE | APR_FLOCK_NONBLOCK))) {
        apr_strerror(err, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Lock failed: %s\n", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    if (0 != (err = apr_file_unlock(f))) {
        apr_strerror(err, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Unlock failed: %s\n", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

    apr_pool_destroy(pool);
    apr_terminate();
    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Ensure that your `apr-devel` RPM package or `libapr1-dev` Debian package or equivalent is installed, then build and run the test using

```
cc -o locktest locktest.c $(apr-1-config --includes --cflags --link-ld --libs)
./locktest /path/to/repo/db/txn-current-lock
```

… ideally running as the webserver user, if using a Subversion server.

---

One surprising possible reason for failing to obtain a lock is if the repository resides on a filesystem mounted using NFS, and the NFS client is unable to write to `/var/lib/nfs` — perhaps due to the `/var` partition being full.